# How do I replace line break with "\n" with java?

Tags: java, replace, newline

I want to replace newline with "\n" but my code isn't working.

```
str.replaceAll("\n","\n"));
```

Expected: "Hello\n World"

Actual:

"Hello

World"

Comment: If you look closely at your code why do you expect anything to happen if you replace something with the exact same thing? You might want to replace it `\\n`.

Comment: Ok, it's clear the expected and actual results but. Can you specify the **input**?

Comment: I was reading the str from txt file containing "Hello(line break) World"

Comment: str.replace("\\n", System.getProperty("line.separator"));

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you want the backslash to show up you have to escape it. Otherwise it will be interpreted as a new line.

```
str = str.replaceAll("\n","\\\\n"));
```

Comment: Doesn't this give "Hello n world"?

Comment: it outputs "Hellon World" for me

Comment: Yes we need the escaped backslash seperatly. Edited the answer

Comment: Great! I'll put this up as the answer, thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Try this.

```
class Scratch {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Hello\n world".replace("\n", "\\n"));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use 3 approach below to do your code work fine:

```
#1
text = str.replace("\n", "\\n");

#2
text = str.replace(System.getProperty("line.separator"), "\\n");

#3
text = text.replaceAll("\\n", "\\\\n");
```

Comment: Approach #3 will not produce two characters ``\`` and `n` but single linebreak character. ``\`` is also special in regex replacement part because it has `$` metacharacter which can be used as `$groupID` or `${groupName}` to reuse match from capturing-groups. To let us escape `$` regex also uses ``\`` here which makes ``\`` metacharacter, so to escape ``\`` we need another ``\``. So we need to escape ``\`` twice, once in regex, ``\\`` and once in String literal ``"\\\\"``.

Comment: @Pshemo , thanks for your advice , i edit my answer

Answer (score 0):

'\n' means a new line like '\t' is a tab, '\' is an escape character it means that the character that comes after it is not handled as normal text (you should read about escape character for more details), so if you want to actually type '\' then you need to represent it with '\' this mean that if you want to have '\n' you should type '\n'. Please check escape character don't just use this info without understanding it.

Comment: Is this a comment on one of the answers, or even response to one of the comments?

Answer (score 0):

You can use following code to do that

```
String hello = "hello\nworld";
hello=hello.replaceAll("\\n", "\\\\n");
System.out.println(hello);
```